# Write an xml file with external nodes

Tags: java, jaxb, stax

I need to generate a large xml file with a simple structure

```
<file>
 <details>
 <d1></d1>
 ...
 <dn></dn>
 <task></task>
 <task></task>
 ...
 <task></task>
 </details>
</file>
```

I'm using JAXB for the Xml - POJO mapping. So I have a FilePojo that has a list of tasks. The tasks are stored in database because they are in large numbers so I can't just retrieve them in memory all at once.

How can I do the marshal action?

The code I have so far related to this action using a `XMLStreamWriter`

```
XMLOutputFactory factory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
XMLStreamWriter xmlsw = new IndentingXMLStreamWriter(factory.createXMLStreamWriter(writerXml));

JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(File.class);
Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
JAXBElement<File> jx = new JAXBElement<>(new QName("http://namespace", "File"), File.class, file);
m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);

m.marshal(jx, xmlsw);
```

The file object has all the details except the List of Tasks.

Comment: Tricky. Could you share your POJO for File and how the List of Tasks fits into that? My best guess would be to not map your List<Task> but instead provide some List<TaskKey> that you can keep in memory (only the IDs for your tasks) and then provide XmlMapper based custom marshaller on TaskKey to pull data from DB as needed. But that's still assuming stuff will be written per field on underlying stream - and not just into a buffer to be returned once all marshalling done...

Comment: @Jan I don't have an exact POJO because this is a simplification of the real system. Can you please give me more details related to the custom marshaller? How would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this lengthy example (compile and run - all classes included).

In this example, class `Details` holds two lists (not sure what you have) - one with tasks - but no annotation, so this would not be used in JAXB, and one with `TaskId` objects that hold only a reference to one task. I added custom Marshaller for TaskId objects and told JAXB to write them out as "task". If JAXB streams the output out, you should be able to do "load one at a time" using this code. If JAXB buffers all output you'd have to think of other ways to generate XML as you stated you cannot load all tasks into memory.

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter;

import my.test.XmlOut.TaskId;
import my.test.XmlOut.TaskListAdapter;
import my.test.XmlOut.File.Details;
import my.test.XmlOut.File.Task;
import my.test.XmlOut.File.TaskList;

public class XmlOut {
public static class TaskId {

}

public static class TaskListAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String,TaskId> {

    @Override
    public TaskId unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(TaskId v) throws Exception {
        //Load your actual TASK here and convert it to XML (you could use JAXB as well)
        return "HERE GOES MY TASK XML";
    }

}

@XmlRootElement
public static class File {

    public static class TaskList {
        int fileid;

    }

    public static class Task {
        String id;

        @XmlElement
        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }

    public static class Details {
        String d1;
        String dn;
        private List<Task> tasks;
        private List<TaskId> taskIds;

        public void setTasks(List<Task> t) {
            tasks = t;
        }

        @XmlElement
        public String getD1() {
            return d1;
        }

        public void setD1(String d1) {
            this.d1 = d1;
        }

        @XmlElement
        public String getDn() {
            return dn;
        }

        public void setDn(String dn) {
            this.dn = dn;
        }

        @XmlElement(name="task") 
        @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(TaskListAdapter.class)
        public List<TaskId> getTaskIds() {
            return taskIds;
        }

        public void setTaskIds(List<TaskId> asList) {
            taskIds = asList;
        }



    }

    protected Details details = new Details();

    @XmlElement
    public Details getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(Details details) {
        this.details = details;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        File file = new File();
        file.setDetails(new Details());
        file.getDetails().setD1("d1");
        file.getDetails().setTaskIds(Arrays.asList(new TaskId(), new TaskId(), new TaskId(), new TaskId(), 
                new TaskId(), new TaskId(), new TaskId()));
        XMLOutputFactory factory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(File.class);
        Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);

        JAXBElement<File> jx = new JAXBElement<>(new QName("http://namespace", "File"), File.class, file);          
        m.marshal(jx, System.out);          
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Can't we determine after executing your example if JAXB streams or buffers the output?

Comment: With just writing out some minimal data outout is not produced in TaskItem Marshaller. But there might be internal buffer that's flushed when full..? O